# Bower dependencies duplication

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, package, bower

I've got this problem, I'm using bower as a package manager for my project and one of my core packages is

```
bootstrap-sass-twbs
```

everything is perfect but than... I wanted to add a lightbox like gallery package that is based  on twitter's bootstrap. But the problem is... this package requires 'classical'

```
bootstrap
```

package and at the end I have both:

```
bootstrap-sass-twbs
bootstrap
```

which in my opinion is one of the worst things that can happen (library duplication). Any one know how to solve it?

Comment: Then again, this enables use you to use module A, depending on library L@1.0.4 and module B, depending on library L@2.0.8, living happily under one roof. This way you'll never run into version conflicts.

Comment: @m90 good point... but is it a good practice?

Comment: Usually, you'll have a build process that sorts stuff like this out for you and removes unneeded cruft before shipping to production (http://addyosmani.com/blog/removing-unused-css/ as an example). Don't know to which extent this is feasible for you. Maybe you're better off adjusting your lightbox to bootstrap 3 yourself.

Comment: @m90 sounds reasonable, thank you.